# How can I get return True with multiple condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***At first I declare a object  like that:***

```
const initialFilesUpload = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    type: '',
    uploadDate: '',
    revisionNo: '',
    documentCategory: null
};
```

Then my Condition is :

```
console.log( uploadFiles.name === '' && uploadFiles.revisionNo === '' && uploadFiles.documentCategory === null );
```

I have face the problem to return ***false***  if a condition change!

***like that : uploadFiles.name==='Doc File'***

Now I wanna get ***true*** after every condition checking!

Please help me!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand but are you trying to log if any of them satisfies instead of all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add more clarity to your question.

Below are few assumptions with relevant code snippets

1. Print `true` if [name, revisionNo, documentCategory] `all` are either empty or undefined, else print `false`

```js
console.log( !uploadFiles.name && !uploadFiles.revisionNo && !uploadFiles.documentCategory);
```

2. Print `true` if [name, revisionNo, documentCategory] `any` of these are either empty or undefined, else print `false`

```js
console.log( !uploadFiles.name || !uploadFiles.revisionNo || !uploadFiles.documentCategory);
```

Comment: Thanks. 2 solution is working good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have face the problem to return false if a condition change!

That's normal, you are using `&&` condition which means "and". So if at least one condition isn't successfull, you will have false.

If you want to check, for example, if at least one of the tree condition is true you have to use the "or" operator `||`, example:

```js
console.log( uploadFiles.name === '' || uploadFiles.revisionNo === '' || uploadFiles.documentCategory === null );
```